# How to use flash document class only for simple form?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm very beginner in Flash. I'm trying to use document class only. I created a textBox and setting some value with

textBox1.text = 10;

When running, the stage flickers.

How can I avoid this flickering effect without using code in timeline but only in document class ?

Update: Would like code in both cases:

- all programmatically (no objects on stage at design time)
- put elements on stage with no actionscript in timelines and control them in document class with actionscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use the document class, it may be better not to add a textfield directly onto the stage. Instead , create your TextField, make sure it is dynamic , give it an instance name, select it and convert it into a MovieClip,

In your Document class :

```
     //MyMovieClip would be your MovieClip name
     private var textBox:MovieClip = new MyMovieClip();

     private function init():void
     {
          //instanceName is your TextField instance name...
          textBox.instanceName.text = 10;
          addChild( textBox );
     }
```

Basically , the whole idea is to design / create your elements on the Stage , save them as MovieClips , remove them from the stage, then call them and manipulate them from your DocumentClass...

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted. Would also like alternative to just put graphics element on stage and control them in document class with actionscript.

Comment: I don't understand textBox:MovieClip : I want to reference the component in toolbox rather.

Answer (score 0):

Check that either your main time only has one frame, or that your textfield stretches across the entire main timeline. Or call stop() in the constructor of you document class.

Comment: When programming using the document class, one doesn't have to call `stop()` in the constructor.

Comment: @jase21 Don't know what you are talking about. If you want the main timeline to stop on the first frame, you are gonna' have to call stop on it. Whether it's from the document class or where ever!